# Strategy for managing lookup data across SQL environments

Tags: sql, environment

We have Dev, Stage, and Prod environments in SQL. Our application has lots of lookup and configuration type data, sometimes nested in parent - child relationships. We've tried storing this setup type data in various tables as you would normally in SQL, with parent ID Identity seeds, and child data referencing parent data by parent ID.

This works fine in a single environment, but as soon as something is added, say in Prod, then Stage ID's are out of synch. Or say some config is done in stage and prod at the same time, so the Parent ID might be the same but the data itself is for different things. So WidgetMasterABC in Prod has parentid = 3, but WidgetMasterABC in Stage has parentid = 22. And so the child references are off too.

Upshot: what strategies are best for maintaining this type of changing config data? Is using identities basically a no-no? Unique id's (but not identities) like when you get the largest # and add 1, presents the same problem.

Comment: Surely it's just a matter of upgrade scripts which are run as new versions/changes are rolled out?

Comment: Can you add a column to the setup tables for the Environment? Then, you can check the current environment and grab only the relevant info.

Comment: The problem is the identities get out of synch and actually refer to different things, like id=3 refers to WidgetA in Stage, but in Prod someone ALSO setup WidgetA and it has id=7.